# When creating tuples as dictionary elements in Python 3, it says elements must be int or slices

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

It works when I create *string tuples as an element of **a tuple*** but doesn't work when I create *string tuples as an element of **a dictionary*** in Python 3.

The Python shell status is this:

```
    =============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
>>> keys = ("one","two","three")
>>> 
>>> TD1 = [["\0" for x in range(2)] for y in range(3)]
>>> TD1[0] = ("First","Tuple")
>>> TD1
[('First', 'Tuple'), ['\x00', '\x00'], ['\x00', '\x00']] 
>>> #string tuples as an element of a tuple created
>>> 
>>> TD2 = [["\0" for x in range(2)] for y in keys]
>>> TD2["one"] = ("First","Tuple")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    TD2["one"] = ("First","Tuple")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>>> #string tuples as an element of a dictionary not created
>>>
```

Can someone tell how to do it...I wanna create string tuples as an element of a dictionary. I want a structure like this referenced under same name:

> "color" = ("Red","Blue","Green","Yellow","Pink")
>
> "animal" = ("Lion","Horse","Kangaroo","Dog","Bull")
>
> "bird" = ("Parrot","Nightingale","Hawk","Sparrow","Eagle")
>
> "fruit" = ("Mango","Apple","Cherry","Grapes","Banana")

Comment: `TD2` isn't a dictionary?

Comment: `TD2` is simply a 2d list, not a dictionary.

Comment: @RisingUnderDog, why are you indexing a list with a string? What do you expect from `TD2["one"]` ?

Comment: You are right, it has to be curly braces... it's not a dictionary for sure :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that TD2 is a list, not a dictionary. If you want to get a dictionary you can use dict comprehension:

```
 TD2 = {y: ["\0" for x in range(2)] for y in keys}
```

Notice the curly brackets and the `key: value` expression.

Comment: Yeah, I should use braces for dictionary.
 `TD2 = {y: ["\0" for x in range(2)] for y in keys}`
This works... thank you very much.. :)

Comment: @RisingUnderDog could you accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: This was the problem, what I expected was to a have a dictionary who's elements would be tuples (having string elements).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code but working. You need to make the dictionary a dictionary. Your TD2 is a list.

```
keys = ("one","two","three")

TD1 = [["\0" for x in range(2)] for y in range(3)]
TD1[0] = ("First","Tuple")
print(TD1)

TD2 = dict.fromkeys(keys, ["\0" for x in range(2)])
TD2["one"] = ("First","Tuple")
print(TD2)
```